# jQuery toggle a button value using .prop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, toggle

i am trying to make the value of a button change when hovering, but then change back on  mouse off.

To change the value this does work:

```
$(".followbuttony").hover(function () {
     $(".followbuttony").toggle('value', 'Unfollow');
});
```

But of course it stays that value. The problem is that the button value is dynamically loaded in the first place so i cant just set another value on mouse off.

Any help on making this a toggle style action?

I have this jsfiddle to show:

http://jsfiddle.net/T5Vm2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way to do it, you have to use both handlers in `hover()`

```
$(".followbuttony").hover(function () {
     $(".followbuttony").val('Unfollow');
},function() {
     $(".followbuttony").val('Following');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T5Vm2/1/)

Personally, I like this better

```
$(".followbuttony").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(".followbuttony").val(e.type=='mouseenter'?'Unfollow':'Following');
});
```

To store the initial value, change it, and then get it back, you can do :

```
$(".followbuttony").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type=='mouseenter') {
        $(this).data('val', this.value).val('Unfollow');
    }else{
        $(this).val($(this).data('val'));
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T5Vm2/2/)

Comment: the thing is a i have a value taken from the database as part of the value. So it has following - (the amount of followers). Is this too much work for a simple jquery function?

Comment: Nope, you need to store the value somewhere, and then get it back, give me a sec to write the code

Comment: okay thanks, i understand that part of it. Just didnt know if there was a way to simply toggle the value. Thanks for the code help though :)

Comment: Just added, you have to store the inital value, and jQuery has `data()` which is a neat place to store data, and then just get it back again.

Comment: wow thanks, thats a nice function :) shall remember that one for the future. Always learning on here. Shall mark as accepted in a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two functions to hover event like this :

```
$(".followbuttony").hover(function () {
         $(".followbuttony").prop('value', 'Unfollow');
},function() {
         $(".followbuttony").prop('value', 'Following');

});
```

[Click here - Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35yma/)